# How to use image data in js for paths?

Tags: javascript, image, html

I am knocking up a html5, js, css3 app where my images shirt can change color.

My mock-up at the moment has the base image and the shirt image (.png) on top.

To get the alternative color (I intend 20 or so options & the same for trousers, shoes etc), I could have a dedicated .png file for each color, but that seems overkill.

Using paths with stroke() & fill() will achieve what I want, but I can't find a method in documentation that explains how js can use paths in an image file (or what file format that might be). The examples I find draw the path within js.

Any suggestions re paths or perhaps alternative/better ways of achieving this?

Cheers

Comment: Raphael.js comes to mind if you already have paths.  It would be easy if javascript had an xpm image format.

Comment: Checking out Raphael led to checking out & experimenting with svg images. I think svg is what I was looking for, I have it basically working I just need to find a free & easy to use png to svg converter (Inkscape has come up). Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: inkscape is a good starting point, but with raphael, you only need the paths it generates (inkscape adds a lot of superfluos tags) and you can also cut the size by over half by removing white space and reducing the precision. ex: change 12.193456 to 12.2  Keep in mind that you can include a png in an svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to make a shirt.png image with transparency where the shirt is. You could then give the  a CSS background to colorize the shirt. Should be the easiest and most flexible way I think.

Comment: ahhh, that took a minute to click. So have the image surrounding the shirt the same color as I want the background to be, leaving the transparent shirt itself easily changeable using the underlying css background. I like that and will use it elsewhere, but in this case the image is placed over top of a model image.